# Find String Comparing with Array

Tags: c#, linq

this solution is give me the result expected. I'm trying to look into string if a value of stringToCheck  Exists! but I would like to have it on a nice way, linq or less code.

```
string stringToCheck = "testtest";
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "testtest", "test1test2", "test2text1" };
foreach (string x in stringArray)
{
    if (x.Contains(stringToCheck))
    {
        //    System.Console.Write("{0} ", x.Contains(stringArray[0]));
        string result = "No Found";
        switch (stringToCheck)
        {
            case "text1":
                if (x.Contains(stringArray[0]))
                    result = "text1";
                break;
            case "testtest":
                if (x.Contains(stringArray[1]))
                    result = "testtest";
                break;
        }
        System.Console.Write("{0} ", result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

EDIT : Code doesnt do what I Expect, if I change `string stringToCheck = "testtest longer string";` I want it to return *testtest* With this code, nothing is returned

Comment: Trust me. Your code is beautiful (read understandable) the way it is.

Comment: "nice code" and "less code" are often the exact opposite of eachother. Don't try to cram everything in LINQ either: it's a serious e-peen win but it comes - in your case - with horrible readability and maintainability.

Comment: *If it is not broke, don't fix it.*

Comment: in your loop if you pass the contains check you know what value of x is contained in the string. What is the switch statement meant to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to go is to use the `Intersect` extension method, after performing a `Split` operation on the search string:

```
var q = stringToCheck.Split(' ').Intersect(stringArray);
```

Further applying a `FirstOrDefault` on your linq query gets you the first string matched in the '*string to check*' sequence, or null if nothing is found.

```
string sFound = q.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That! Thanks, I elaborate the question poorly initialy and had vote down. but this is it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example does not do what you say it does...
You say that you want this: "I'm trying to look into string if a value of my Array Exists"

Looking in an array to check if it contains a certain value, can be done with the `Contains`method:

```
Console.WriteLine(stringArray.Contains(stringToCheck) ? stringToCheck : "No found");
```

Comment: Your are right. I meant stringToCheck, I want to compare the String against a value on the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Contains** returns true or false.
It indicates whether the IEnumerable collection has an element matching the argument. It acts upon any `IEnumerable` collection when the `System.Linq` namespace is included.

```
string stringToCheck = "testtest";
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "testtest", "test1test2", "test2text1" };
bool b = stringArray.Contains(stringToCheck);
```

Note:
Contains is an `extension method`, and can be called on arrays, Lists and certain other collections.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, People have already answered `Contains()` another method that you can use is `Any()`:

```
stringArray.Any(m => m == stringToCheck)
```

You can also use `Array.IndexOf()`:

```
Array.IndexOf(stringArray, stringToCheck)>-1 ? true : false
```

However out of all the methods it seems that using a `Array.IndexOf()` will be the fastest. You can see detailed comparisons [here](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000682.html). When you are trying to search in arrays of millions in size then:

**Results:**

`foreach loop search` :    391 ms

`for loop search` :    412 ms

`Contains() method search` :  185 ms

`Any() method search` :   1011 ms

`Via Index` :     141 ms